# Parse issue when using instancetype in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I met one issue when using **instancetype** keyword in objective-c. X-Code show error Expected a type when trying to building project.

```
+ (instancetype)clientWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url;
```

Do you have any idea on this problem?

Comment: What's the implementation of the the method?

Comment: @Abizern

+ (instancetype)clientWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url {
    return [[self alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
}

But in my opinion, maybe issue doesn't come from implementation, but compiler show error at (instancetype).

Comment: What version of Xcode and what compiler is selected in the build settings?

Comment: @rmaddy: Xcode I'm using with Apple LLVM compiler 3.0.

Comment: What version of Xcode? And you might need LLVM 4.0 and later for `instancetype`.

Comment: @rmaddy: I'm using Xcode 4.2. And how can I do to upgrade compiler for Xcode?

Comment: You need Xcode 4.6. You need to use the latest version anyway if you plan to put your app in the store.

Comment: @rmaddy: I'm using MacOS 10.6.8, so if I want to upgrade to Xcode 4.6, that means I must upgrade OS as well, don't I?

Comment: @EdwardTran That is correct; you'll need to upgrade to the latest OS + the latest Xcode.

Comment: Thanks every body for your help :)

Comment: @EdwardTran Xcode 4.6 will work with 10.7 and later but Xcode 5 will be out soon (it already is out in beta) and it will require 10.8 and later.